# Pygame, sounds(mp3) don't play

Tags: python, tkinter, audio, pygame

I'm trying to play sound files (.mp3) with Pygame and Tkinter but when I start it I never hear anything.
This is the code:

```
from tkinter import StringVar, filedialog
import os 
import tkinter
import pygame
from pygame import *
 
root = tkinter.Tk()
path = filedialog.askdirectory()

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

def startm():
    if clicked.get() == mp3[0]:

        pygame.mixer.music.load(mp3[0])
        

if not path:
    print('Canceled')
else:
    mp3 = [fn for fn in os.listdir(path) if fn.lower().endswith('.mp3') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, fn))]
    clicked = StringVar()
    tkinter.OptionMenu(root, clicked, mp3[0], *mp3).pack()

    w = tkinter.Button(root,text="start",command=startm)
    w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

the programme run but the sound don't work

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to note here as to why the audio is not playing and why the logic is kind of flawed.

1. The reason why no audio is played is because you are just loading the music, you are not playing it. To play a music, you have to say `pygame.mixer.music.play()`.
2. Now even if you add `pygame.mixer.music.play()`, you will notice nothing plays. It is because the `if` condition there is kind of pointless. The line `if clicked.get() == mp3[0]:` means: Only if the selection from the optionmenu is same as the first item in the `mp3` list, play the song. But the user should be able to play any song they choose, not only the first song in the list. So you should remove it.
3. Now you will notice that despite removing this, you will get another error because the file path does not exists. Basically, `clicked.get()` will be the file name only and not the file path. Using file name like that will force python to check for relative path in which the song exists. But there is no relative path such that the path is true. So you have to use absolute path.
4. Now to use absolute path, you will notice that the absolute path of the song will be showed in the optionmenu. But  you don't want that, you just need the song name displayed on the optionmenu, but you want to play the song with absolute path, so there must be some sort of mapping like:

```
{ "song_name": "D:/path/to/dir/song_name.mp3" } # Key will be displayed in optionmenu but value will be used in `pygame` to load the music.
```

So the code with the above mentioned changes are inflicted is:

```
from glob import glob # (5) Mentioned in extra changes
from pathlib import Path # (6)
...
...

def startm():
    song_name = clicked.get() 
    song_abs_path = songs[song_name] # (4) Get the absolute path from the songs dictionary 
    # if clicked.get() == mp3[0]: # (2) Getting rid of this line
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song_abs_path) # (3) Loading song with its absolute path and not relative path 
    pygame.mixer.music.play() # (1) Play the song after loading it

if not path:
    print('Canceled')
else:
    mp3_abs_paths = glob(f"{path}/*.mp3") # (5) Choose all the mp3 files from the given path
    mp3_names = [Path(path).name for path in mp3_abs_paths] # (6) List of all the song names
    songs = {k:v for k,v in zip(mp3_names,mp3_abs_paths)} # (4) A dictionary in the format mentioned above above
    
    clicked = StringVar()
    tkinter.OptionMenu(root, clicked, mp3_names[0], *mp3_names).pack()

    w = tkinter.Button(root,text="start",command=startm)
    w.pack()
```

The changes I mentioned above are marked in the comment of the code above to make it more understandable.

A few extra changes that I made:

5. I introduced a module that will make your life a bit more easier, `glob`. It is basically a substitute for what you did with the list comprehension for `mp3`.
6. I used `Path` from `pathlib`, because it is better than `os.path` in many ways and it also makes things a bit more simpler in the future for path related operations than `os.path`.

Something additional I would do is to replace `OptionMenu` as it is kind of *tacky* IMO. A very good substitute for it is the `ttk.Combobox`:

```
from tkinter import ttk

clicked = StringVar() # You can also get rid of this and start using `combo.get()` as it gives same value as `clicked.get()` and `clicked` becomes useless then.
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=mp3_names, state='readonly',textvariable=clicked)
combo.current(0) # Make the first item of the list as the current selection
combo.pack()
```

Comment: it's giving me that 

  File "c:\Users\python\Desktop\....py", line 16, in startm
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song_abs_path)
pygame.error: mixer not initialized

Comment: @walonet Are you sure you included `pygame.init()` and `pygame.mixer.init()` like said in your code? I think you missed it which is why `load` is coming on 16th line.

Comment: now his giving me that:
File "c:\Users\python\Desktop\....py", line 22, in startm
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.error: mpg123_seek: Invalid RVA mode. (code 12)

Comment: @walonet That is prolly the problem with your audio file. It works fine on my 3 systems. So try again with a proper mp3 file. You can google the error and you will see that it is the problem of the file.